# What is causing "Directory not empty" errors?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I've written a script that is *mostly* working for me. However, the two `rmdir` commands at the end are sometimes returning `Directory not empty` errors. How do I beat this? I tried adding  `r` and then `-rf` which returned `Illegal option` errors.

I'm a rookie, and I'd be grateful for any help. Here is the full shell script, which, again, is *mostly* working beautifully:

```
if [[ -z "${1}" ]]; then
  die "FolderName Required"
fi

newDirName="DirectoryName"
newBaseDir="/Users/JSG/Desktop/DataFarm/$1/"
/bin/mkdir -p $newBaseDir/{ProtectedOrig,Data}

echo -n "---Data Folder Setup

---Data Introduction

---Data Audit/Manipulation

---Data Queries" > $newBaseDir/Data/$1_DataJournal.txt

ditto NewData/ NewDataCopy
fab deploy_data_to_s3:data=*
mv NewData/ $newBaseDir/ProtectedOrig/NewData
mv NewDataCopy/ $newBaseDir/Data/NewDataCopy 
mv $newBaseDir/Data/NewDataCopy/* $newBaseDir/Data/
rmdir $newBaseDir/Data/NewDataCopy
mv $newBaseDir/ProtectedOrig/NewData/* $newBaseDir/ProtectedOrig/
rmdir $newBaseDir/ProtectedOrig/NewData
chflags -R uchg $newBaseDir/ProtectedOrig/
mkdir NewData
```

What am I missing? And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the `rmdir` command, you need to add the `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` flag so it deletes the directory even if files are in there like so:

```
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty $newBaseDir/Data/NewDataCopy
```

You could also just use `rm -r` too:

```
rm -r $newBaseDir/Data/NewDataCopy
```

From the [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rmdir):

> rmdir will not remove a directory if it is not empty in UNIX. The correct way to remove a directory and all its contents recursively is with the rm command.

Comment: Added `rm -r` and it now the script works like a charm. However, `ignore-fail-on-non-empty` returned `Illegal option` errors. Any idea why? And thank you very, very much.

Comment: Possibly that flag was deprecated or not used on Unix anymore. Using rm -r is the preferred way anyway for removing a directory which is empty or even non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

Check for any files in the directory that start with `.`. I note you're moving `*`, but if there's a file called, for example, `.hello`, then `*` will not match this file and as a result the directory will not be empty when you come to do an rmdir.